# Microsoft Word Styles; Apply only text color and spacing?

Tags: microsoft-word, format, styles, microsoft, indent

I'm new here!
I love using the styles in MS Word, super helpful keeping the document consistent with formatting.  My only issue is that some of my text have different indentations.  So when I apply the style, they remove the indentation and alight all to the same indent.  Any way I can just apply the text color and no spacing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Color can be controlled using a Character style, but spacing is controlled in paragraph styles, which will also involve indentation.

Define, create, new paragraph styles to handle the indentation and spacing you want. They can also include font formatting like color and bold.

For formatting on parts of a paragraph, use character styles.

Here is my writing on the [importance of styles in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview). Here is my writing on the [differences between paragraph and character styles](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Character).